# What does AWS EC2 DDOS protection shield throw when activated? HTTP(S) 503?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ddos

What does Amazon AWS EC2 DDOS protection shield throw when activated? HTTP(S) 503?

At which amount can this happen? 5000 - 10000 requests at "the same time"?

Is this public info and available somewhere?

Comment: DDoS mitigation just drops the traffic entirely.

Comment: What? Why are you making this comment? }:‑)

Answer (score 1):

What Michael wanted to say is that if a DDOS attack is detected, let's say from IP X, an ACL is triggered which blocks all traffic from IP X to your service.

However, if you use AWS WAF to protect your web service, an HTTP status code would be 403 (Forbidden).

You should check the documentation and read through how the AWS Shield Advanced service works.

Here is the link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-dg.pdf#ddos-overview

Comment: Just a note that Shield Advanced costs (from memory) US$3000 a month. Shield Standard is what AWS provides to all customers for free, which has a smaller feature set but sufficient for most needs. Shield Standard has no user interface, it's always on.

Comment: Agree, it is not a cheap solution. The AWS Shield Standard provides Layer 3 and 4 protection. I understood that @uav is looking for Layer 7 protection, so I hope he or she has a sufficient budget to spend.